# Can I get a trimmed mean of all columns in a dataframe with nan values?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy

The problem is that I want to get the trimmed mean of all the columns in a pandas dataframe (i.e. the mean of the values in a given column, excluding the max and the min values). It's likely that some columns will have nan values. Basically, I want to get the exact same functionality as the pandas.DataFrame.mean function, except that it's the trimmed mean.

The obvious solution is to use the scipy tmean function, and iterate over the df columns. So I did:

```
import scipy as sp

trim_mean = []

for i in data_clean3.columns:
    trim_mean.append(sp.tmean(data_clean3[i]))
```

This worked great, until I encountered nan values, which caused tmean to choke. Worse, when I dropped the nan values in the dataframe, there were some datasets that were wiped out completely as they had an nan value in every column. This means that when I amalgamate all my datasets into a master set, there'll be holes on the master set where the trimmed mean should be.

Does anyone know of a way around this? As in, is there a way to get tmean to behave like the standard scipy stats functions and ignore nan values?

(Note that my code is calculating a big number of descriptive statistics on large datasets with limited hardware; highly involved or inefficient workarounds might not be optimal. Hopefully, though, I'm just missing something simple.)

(**EDIT**: Someone suggested in a comment (that has since vanished?) that I should used the trim_mean scipy function, which allows you to top and tail a specific proportion of the data. This is just to say that this solution won't work for me, as my datasets are of unequal sizes, so I cannot specify a fixed proportion of data that will be OK to remove in every case; it must always just be the max and the min values.)

Comment: will this work for you `(pd.DataFrame(data_clean3.sum()-data_clean3.max()-data_clean3.min()).T).mean()`.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good stab at what I need, but I there might be a problem, in that the max and min values may occur more than once in each column. Thus, subtracting each value from the sum of the column might not accurately reflect the trimmed mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you colud use df.mean(skipna =True) [DataFrame.mean](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[5, 1, 'a'], [6, 2, 'b'],[7, 3, 'd'],[np.nan, 4, 'e'],[9, 5, 'f'],[5, 1, 'g']],  columns =  ["A", "B", "C"])
print df1
df1 = df1[df1.A != df1.A.max()] # Remove max values
df1 = df1[df1.A != df1.A.min()] # Remove min values

print "\nDatafrmae after removing max and min\n"
print df1
print "\nMean of A\n"

print df1["A"].mean(skipna =True)
```

output

```
         A  B  C
0  5.0  1  a
1  6.0  2  b
2  7.0  3  d
3  NaN  4  e
4  9.0  5  f
5  5.0  1  g

Datafrmae after removing max and min

     A  B  C
1  6.0  2  b
2  7.0  3  d
3  NaN  4  e

Mean of A

6.5
```

Comment: This is a handy approach; thanks very much! For some reason, the particular syntax didn't work (a version issue?) so I implemented it instead by looping across columns and replacing the max/min values with 'NaN'. I.e.

`code` for i in data_clean2.columns:
    trimmed_mean.append(data_clean2[i].replace(data_clean2[i].max(),             'NaN')) `code`

Then, I used the standard pandas mean to get the trimmed mean. Thanks for the idea!

Answer (score 2):

consider `df`

```
np.random.seed()
data = np.random.choice((0, 25, 35, 100, np.nan),
                        (1000, 2),
                        p=(.01, .39, .39, .01, .2))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=list('AB'))
```

Construct your mean using sums and divide by relevant normalizer.

```
(df.sum() - df.min() - df.max()) / (df.notnull().sum() - 2)

A    29.707674
B    30.402228
dtype: float64
```

---

```
df.mean()

A    29.756987
B    30.450617
dtype: float64
```

---

Comment: Thanks, but as with shivsn's suugestion above, isn't this likely to prove problematic if the max or min value occurs more than once?

Comment: @Lodore66 Depends, what do you want to happen if it happens more than once?

Comment: Ideally, I want all instances of the max/min to be removed from the df, so that the mean is only of values in between the two. I suppose this makes the divisor the problem, as there may be more that 2 values removed.